# What would be the best practice to implement hierarchical data in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nested

I have a very simple dataset, consisting of

- a date (object) for every day over multiple years and
- a value that belongs to a date.

I need to look at that data on the level of days, months and years (and flowing time intervals, like e.g. 30 days). The data is obtained from a csv file.

What would you suggest, is the best way, to (conceptually) prepare the data? Should I, when reading the data immediately nest it (year > month > day - value) and also calculate everything I need to plot (like averages and the likes) and save it with my data (e.g. data.year.monthXY.avg = z)?

Or should I leave the data as is (at its most basic form, a day and its value) and do all the calculations later in the script?

I have little experience in handling data and D3s best practices and would appreciate any advice you have for me on that topic.

I feel like, there is not need to prep the date, because all the info is already contained in the date object and the value, and all the calculation can be done on the fly. (I have to admit, though, that I don't know exactly how i can tell D3 to, say, create the average of a month, without first creating a new dataset that just includes this exact month. That might be another question though, depending how you suggest I should sort my data.) But on the other hand nesting data where possible seems like a good idea, in particular for making use of D3s strength in that regard and its benefits for other/future visual representations.

Comment: I would personally process the data beforehand, and then load the processed data in with d3js, you then don't have to wait for the processing to finish before you can display the graph you're trying to create. I guess it depends on how large your dataset is though. Regarding how it should be nested, I think this would depend on what visualisation you want to generate. Do you know how you're going to visualise your data yet?

Comment: The amount of data is very small and easily loaded on the fly. I actually like to not have to process it beforehand (less steps, and js seems to do fine for now). The data will be mostly bar and line charts. But I might add transitions/interactions, that 'zoom' into months/days/hours to show more details of specific dates.

Comment: *"I feel like, there is not need to prep the date"*. Yes, no need to prepare the data. Do any calculation as needed.